# woud like to V in the past

Tags: past-tense

"would like to V" is said to mean "want to V" in the present.
What is its past version? If I want to rewrite the following using a version of "would like to," what should I write?

> John wanted to go home early, so he finished his work soon.

Comment: The past tense of 'would like to' is 'would have liked to'. "John would have liked to go home early, but the task he was working on wasn't finished until nearly five o'clock."

Comment: But the scenario you provdied in the second clause is very different from mine. I'm wondering how to express the idea with "would like to" In the scenario of the OP.

Comment: Your scenario is about a past desire that is unrealized.

Comment: In that case, you could only say something like "John decided/felt/thought that he would like to..."

Comment: Is it a verbosity to say "decided/felt/thought that he would like to..."?

Comment: Not if that is what you mean!

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the sentence in the OP, i.e., "John wanted to go home early, so he finished his work soon"?

Comment: No, but I thought you were asking how to use 'would like to' in the past tense!

Comment: Thank you. I was asking just because Brad said below that my sentence sounds wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "would like to V" is said to mean "want to V" in the present. What is its past version? If I want to rewrite the following using a version of "would like to," what should I write?

> John wanted to go home early, so he finished his work soon.

---

The correct version of "John wanted to go home early, so he finished his work soon" is a little difficult as **your sentence sounds wrong. I cannot imagine a native speaker saying what you have written**. I will try to imagine what you what to say.

My alternatives are

**John finished his work quickly as he wanted to go home early.**

**John would like to go home early, so he needs to finish his work quickly.**

***John would have liked to go home early, but he needed to finish his work** before he left*.

This last sentence is difficult as it is in the past so presumably we would be reporting that he did not leave early as he could not finish his work quickly or that as he completed his work quickly he was able to leave early. However you did not provide any context.

---

**The use of the word Soon**

I would never have used soon in this way. "**so he finished his work soon**". But from your comments I can see that you are struggling to see why. When I looked up the definitions in the dictionary I could see why you did not understand. However in the Cambridge English Dictionary there are some comments about the **use of Grammar related to "soon, fast and quickly"** that may help you to understand the use of the word **"soon"**.

**Grammar - Soon**

> :Soon means ‘a short time after now’ and ‘a short time after a point in the past’. Like many other short adverbs, we can use it in front position, mid position or end position, though **we don’t use it in end position when referring to the past:** …

**Grammar - Fast, quick or quickly?**

> Fast and quick mean moving with great speed. Fast is both an adjective and an adverb. Quick is an adjective and the adverb form is quickly. …

I would advise that if you use **soon in relation to "time"** and **fast or quick in relation to speed** you will not go far wrong. Whilst **for more defining sentences use early or late.**

---

> **early; adjective, adverb** near the beginning of a period of time, or before the usual, expected, or planned time: Ref CED [early](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/early)

All Ref CED [Soon](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soon)  [Quickly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quickly)

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong about 'John wanted to go home early, so he finished his work soon." Do you think "soon" is the culprit, by any chance?

Comment: _Quickly_ is better than _soon_ in this context.

Comment: @Apollyon; I have added a section to my answer, in regard to the use of the word "soon". Hope this helps you.